# standalone concat does not return an observable

Tags: rxjs, concatenation

I'm trying to understand the new observables (rxjs) in terms of lettable operators.  To that end I have the following code

```
        const messagesToDispatch = concat(
            of({ type: 'REGITERING_USER' }).delay(5000),
            of({ type: 'REGISTER_USER_COMPLETE', value })
        ).pipe();

        messagesToDispatch.subscribe(subValue => {
            console.log(subValue);
        });
```

Now when I run the code I get the following error

```
messagesToDispatch.subscribe is not a function
```

However when I try the following it works

```
    concatMap(value => {
        const messagesToDispatch = Observable.concat(
            of({ type: 'REGITERING_USER' }).delay(5000),
            of({ type: 'REGISTER_USER_COMPLETE', value })
        );

        messagesToDispatch.subscribe(subValue => {
            console.log(subValue);
        });
```

Notice I have used Observable.concat instead of just concat.  I'm not sure whats going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `concat` as follows in RxJS6 if you want to run your code without errors:

```
import {concat, of} from 'rxjs';

const messagesToDispatch = concat(
            of({ type: 'REGITERING_USER' }).pipe(delay(5000)),
            of({ type: 'REGISTER_USER_COMPLETE', value })
        );
```

Also note how `pipe` is used.

Comment: thanks for this and it worked.  On the same note I'm now confused with should I import from 'rxjs/operators' as given on the rxjs site or just from 'rxjs'?

Comment: You need to import other operator you use like that, for example import { map, filter, scan } from 'rxjs/operators'; For more details see: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#import-paths